# Docassemble 'autoterms' picking up whole `field' text?

Tags: docassemble

I'm rendering a list of choices using this formula:

```
generic object: DADict
question: |
  (!!!) What is your desired outcome for your property?
fields:
  - "Destroy current property": x.assets['destroy_current_property']
    datatype: radio
    code: property_choices
    help: (!!!) To do
    default: x.assets.destroy_current_property
  - "Donate future property": x.assets['donate_future_property']
    datatype: radio
    code: property_choices
    help: (!!!) To do
    default: x.assets.donate_future_property
```

The choices from the code seem to be working fine, so I'm not going to get into that. The issue I'm having is that I also have a set of autoterms like this:

```
auto terms:
  ...
  - property: |
      prŏp′ər-tē
      <br><br>
      /ˈaset/
      <br><br>
      noun
      <br><br>
      plural noun: properties
      <br><br>
      1. Something owned; a possession.
      <br><br>
      2. A piece of real estate.
      <br><br>
      3. Something tangible or intangible to which its owner has legal title.
```

The auto terms work fine in most places. What's happening here, though, is that the entire "Donate current property" and "donate future property" are being assigned the class `daterm`. So the relevant part of the HTML looks like this:

```
<a tabindex="0" class="daterm" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="bottom" data-content="(!!!) To do" data-original-title="" title="">

Destroy current property

...

</a>
```

And I think it should (or at least I'd like it to) look more like this:

```
<a tabindex="0" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="bottom" data-content="(!!!) To do" data-original-title="" title="">

Destroy current <span class="daterm">property</span>

...

</a>
```

Is there something I can do so that the entire option / choice text is not selected as an autoterm, and only the one auto-text word is selected (i.e. perhaps this is user error)?

Answer (score 1):

I tried to reproduce the issue with this interview:

```
mandatory: True
question: |
  (!!!) What is your desired outcome for your property?
fields:
  - "Destroy current property": bar
    datatype: radio
    code: property_choices
    help: (!!!) To do
  - "Donate future property": foo
    datatype: radio
    code: property_choices
    help: (!!!) To do
---
auto terms:
  property: |
    prŏp′ər-tē
    <br><br>
    /ˈaset/
    <br><br>
    noun
    <br><br>
    plural noun: properties
    <br><br>
    1. Something owned; a possession.
    <br><br>
    2. A piece of real estate.
    <br><br>
    3. Something tangible or intangible to which its owner has legal title.
---
code: |
  property_choices = ['Car', 'House', 'Plane']
```

In the resulting HTML, however, only the word "property" has the class `daterm`.

[image: screenshot]

So I am not sure why the `daterm` encompasses the whole label, unless maybe you are using an old version of docassemble from a time when the `help` associated with a field would highlight the whole field label as a popover with green text. If that is the case, the `help` feature and the `auto terms` will be incompatible.

In general I don't recommend using `auto terms`; using `terms` and explicitly indicating where you want the terms to be highlighted avoids the problems that can happen when terms overlap.

In any case, the way that `terms` and `auto terms` work, the popover link is only going to encompass the term itself, not text around it.